# OK or Bad? - Doctrine DBAL Queries in a PHP Loop

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I could need a little advice.

The task is to generate some statistics from a MySQL-Database-Table. Im using the Doctrine DBAL Class for the queries.

So we have two tables here (reduced as example):

USERS-Table

```
user_id | user_name  | user_gender | ...
---------------------------------------
1234    | Klark Kent | 1           | ...
2468    | Lex Luthor | 1           | ...
3579    | Louis Lane | 2           | ...
....
```

CHECKINS-Table

```
checkin_id | checkin_user_id | checkin_month | ...
--------------------------------------------------
1          | 1234            | 1             | ...
2          | 2468            | 1             | ...
3          | 1234            | 1             | ...
4          | 1234            | 2             | ...
....
```

The Statistics-Result should be like this in the end:

```
Month | All | Male | Female | Unique
------------------------------------
Jan   | 312 | 179  | 133    | 224
Feb   | 295 | 169  | 135    | 218
Mar   | 301 | 154  | 147    | 230
....
```

So basically I did it this way:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {    
  $QB = $DB->createQueryBuilder();  
  $STMT = $QB
      ->select('c.checkin_id')
      ->from(CHECKIN_TABLE, 'c')
      ->innerJoin('c', USER_TABLE, 'u', 'c.checkin_user_id = u.user_id')
      ->where('u.user_gender = 1')
      ->andWhere('c.checkin_month = :month')
      ->setParameter('month', (int)$i)
      ->execute();
  ;
  $stats[$i]['male'] = $STMT->rowCount();
  $QB = $DB->createQueryBuilder();  
  $STMT = $QB
      ->select('c.checkin_id')
      ->from(CHECKIN_TABLE, 'c')
      ->innerJoin('c', USER_TABLE, 'u', 'c.checkin_user_id = u.user_id')
      ->where('u.user_gender = 2')
      ->andWhere('c.checkin_month = :month')
      ->setParameter('month', (int)$i)
      ->execute();
  ;
  $stats[$i]['female'] = $STMT->rowCount();
  $stats[$i]['all'] = $stats[$i]['male']+$stats[$i]['female'];
  $QB = $DB->createQueryBuilder();  
  $STMT = $QB
      ->select('DISTINCT checkin_user_id')
      ->from(CHECKIN_TABLE, 'c')
      ->where('checkin_month = :month')
      ->setParameter('month', (int)$i)
      ->execute();
  ;
  $stats[$i]['unique'] = $STMT->rowCount();
}
```

As you can see I'm running 3 Queries in 12 times loop. As the queries are relatively simple, this might be ok, however I would be glad to hear your opinion if this can be done better?

Maybe SELECT all entries and then do a WHILE-Fetch Loop with a big number of IF Clauses?

```
if ( ($row['checkin_month'] == 1) && ( $row['user_gender'] == 1 ) $stats[1]['male']++;
if ( ($row['checkin_month'] == 1) && ( $row['user_gender'] == 2 ) $stats[1]['female']++;
if ( ($row['checkin_month'] == 2) && ( $row['user_gender'] == 1 ) $stats[2]['male']++;
if ( ($row['checkin_month'] == 2) && ( $row['user_gender'] == 2 ) $stats[2]['female']++;
```

As we are here, one more question. I have read that using DISTINCT to remove duplicate entries is not the best practice, however I have no idea how I could do this otherwise. I have read about WHERE EXISTS but that would not work as I am only querying a single table here for the DISTINCT call, I think.

If you have any hints or ideas let me know.
Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lucky me, I found a solution by myself after reading and searching a lot of things.

So for everyone who might have a similar task, here is how it can be done with a single query.
(However I have no idea how to build this using the Query-Builder, but it works as SQL-Statement.)

```
$SQL = 'SELECT
         c.checkin_month, count(*) AS count,
         count(DISTINCT c.checkin_member_id) AS uniq,
         sum(case when u.user_gender = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS male,
         sum(case when u.user_gender = 2 then 1 else 0 end) AS female
        FROM 
         '.CHECKIN_TABLE.' c,
         '.USER_TABLE.' u
        WHERE
         c.checkin_user_id = u.user_id
        GROUP BY
         c.checkin_month';
$res = $DB->fetchAll($SQL);
```

So less code, less queries, same result.